# Python Pandas add value to a new row if the other is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column and place in it a value from column2 if it's value is not NaN or otherwise value from column1

Initial table:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| name | otherName1 |
| name1 | NaN |
| name2 | otherName2 |
| name3 | otherName3 |
| name3 | NaN |

New Table

| column1 | column2 | NEW column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | otherName1 | otherName1 |
| name1 | NaN | name1 |
| name2 | otherName2 | otherName2 |
| name3 | otherName3 | otherName3 |
| name3 | NaN | name3 |

My code is too slow and believe that there is a faster solution

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     if pd.notnull(row['column2']):
         row['NEW column'] = row['column2']
     else:
         row['NEW column'] = row['column1']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fillna` to fill in the NaN values in `column2` and assign it to a new column:

```
df['NEW column'] = df['column2'].fillna(df['column1'])
```

Output:

```
  column1     column2  NEW column
0    name  otherName1  otherName1
1   name1         NaN       name1
2   name2  otherName2  otherName2
3   name3  otherName3  otherName3
4   name3         NaN       name3
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, always try to avoid iterating through a dataframe if possible! In your case you can use something like `df['new_column'] = np.where(df['column1'].isna(), df['column2'], df['column1']`). `np.where` functions like an "if-else" statement as you can see in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Edit: just saw enke's answer, that's a better approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda function to `apply`:

```
df['new column'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['column2'] if pd.notnull(row['column2'] else row['column1'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['NEW column'] = df.column2
mask = df.column2.isna()
df.loc[mask, 'NEW column'] = df.column1[mask]
```